# C++ making a loosely typed language parser

Tags: c++, scheme, lisp

I'm thinking about implementing a very small loosely typed language in C++.

I know that C and C++ CAN be used to make new programming languages but I'm totally lost on how to get around the strict type enforcement.

I need to be able to store any value (char, int, double, std::string are what I'll support)
And then be able to retrieve it.

I know you can store the type as a string in a structure with a void *. But even after you dereference the value inside, it is hard to find a way to store them all consistently.

I know you can use a templated class but I think it makes it so the members of that class can only be the specified template and even then cannot change type.

I'm making a Lisp variant so I need a Cell class that has an internal value that can be any of the listed types above. (Please look up Lisp "cons" cell to understand why I need a data member that can be reassigned)

EDIT:
Let me add that this will be an interpreted language and will not need to be compiled into raw C++.

Comment: The problems you describe are independent of the typing discipling of the language you implement. If you created a C interpter, you'd have the same problem. You can't set the types in stone at the time the interpreter is compiled, as they depend on the program, which is a run-time thing.

Comment: My first thought was you should look at [PicoLISP](http://picolisp.com/5000/!wiki?Documentation) since they embed the type in the pointer itself

Answer (score 2):

I suggest something like

```
struct Value {
    enum Tag { Char, Int, Double, String } m_Tag;
    union {
        char m_char;
        int m_int;
        double m_double;
        std::string m_string;
    } u;
};
```

Of course this will not work as written because you can not have a type with a constructor (string) in a union.
But C++11 loosened that restriction.

Comment: The other solution is to represent this as an inheritance hierarchy, though this comes with the problems of being open and requiring the visitor pattern to not be entirely untenable

Answer (score 1):

When you create a programming language, the key step is parsing the code and translating it into something else. Where I believe you are getting stuck is in your thinking. You are imagining setting things up in c/c++ so that you will use the actual classes you have made in a 'loosely typed' sort of way. Instead your process will be more like this:

- Read over the text that has been written in your new language
- Figure out what 'type' the author has put in by looking at the text
- generate c/c++ (or any other language) code that will deal with their code appropriately

The final conversion could change their code into something that looks completely different. This is where you would define all of the rules that make your language 'loosely typed'.

Since you are making a loosely typed system on top of a strictly typed system, you would have to define all of the logic for all of the possible cases that you are interested in.

Suffice it to say this is not a task for the feint of heart. Here is a list of tools you are going to need to complete the task (or at least the tools I would use):

- A [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) library to parse their text
- A [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) to define your language
- A [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) to validate the code
- A variety of [object oriented classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) to represent your data
- A [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) to generate the final code
- A whole bundle of knowledge and perseverance

Best of luck.

Comment: I thought the exact same thing when reading this question, +1. May I add a suggestion concerning the scanner/parser? I'd recommend `flexc++` and `bisonc++` as you seem to be working in C++. They both come with good documentation, also about scanning and parsing in general, and generate true C++ code (unlike `flex++` and `bison++` which are merely wrappers). I've had a good experience writing my first and only compiler using these tools!

Answer (score 0):

> I know you can store the type as a string in a structure with a void *. But even after you dereference the value inside, it is hard to find a way to store them all consistently.

What do you mean by saying "store them all **consistently**? They'll **consistently** lie in the place pointed by the pointer. The pointer will **consistently** have the same size, no matter what it will actually store. And you'll be able to **consistently** know the type of the value with the `string` decribing it. You can even use a single `char` to store the type information (since you need only 4 values).

If you want to make a `variable` class, that's probably the only thing you can do - store a *pointer* and *information* about the type it's pointing to.